# Powershell - Remove lines that begin with multiple strings

Tags: powershell

I am hoping someone can help me. I have extracted certificates from a PFX and would like to remove all lines that start with a space, "Bag Attributes", "issuer" and "subject". My input file would look something like this:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: BLAH BLAH
    BLAH BLAH BLAH
subject=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
issuer=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: BLAH BLAH
    BLAH BLAH BLAH
subject=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
issuer=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: BLAH BLAH
    BLAH BLAH BLAH
subject=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
issuer=C = BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And the output should look like the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried using the following which does remove lines beginning with spaces, however have not been able to successfully remove lines starting with "Bag Attrubutes","subject" and "issuer" with { $_ -notmatch "^ ","^subject","^issuer","^Bag Attributes" }

```
Get-Content "C:\ScriptRepository\Certs\CA-Chain.pem" | 
Where { $_ -notmatch "^ " } | 
Set-Content "C:\ScriptRepository\Certs\CA-chain2.pem"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a standard regex operation... You need to read the file via get-content (or one of the .net alterantives) and then check line by line the regex and if its fullfilled, remove the match. I personally prefer the .net regex operations, but the powershell regex operations should be fine too

Comment: Hi  Farbkreis, thanks for the speedy response, I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days trying to get this to work, could you possibly provide an example.

Comment: `BLAH BLAH BLAH` is a bad representation of a certificate which per definition of your question shouldn't have spaces.  So, the question is what *DO* you want to  match ? (and not what you do *not* want to match). e.g. all valid certificate characters (excluding spaces) that start from the beginning to the end of the line: `-Match '^[A-Z,a-z,0-9,=]+$'` (or a specific length  `-Match '^[A-Z,a-z,0-9,=]{8,40}$'` or  `-Match '^[A-Z,a-z,0-9,=]+\s*$'` if you want to accept tailing spaces)

Comment: Hi Farbkreis , my first sentence in my question asks "remove all lines that start with a space, "Bag Attributes", "issuer" and "subject" that all that was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that in a file, just use a `switch` with a very simple regex:

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'X:\InputFile.pfx' {
    '^(Bag|subject|issuer|\s)'  { <# skip these lines #> }
    default { $_ }
}
$result | Set-Content -Path "C:\ScriptRepository\Certs\CA-chain2.pem"
```

Output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
BLAH BLAH BLAH 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                 Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                  Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      Bag         Match the characters “Bag” literally
   |              Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      subject     Match the characters “subject” literally
   |              Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      issuer      Match the characters “issuer” literally
   |              Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, I really appreciate your time for answering this for me, it has worked perfectly.